Zephyr RTOS: how to know which HW/device allows to test which sample?
Zephyr RTOS: how to know which HW/device allows to test which sample?
The zephyr project comes with lots of examples: for instance zephyrproject/zephyr/samples/drivers/gnss, how to know which device/HW to buy to build/run this example?
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/hardware/peripherals/gnss.html
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/drivers/gnss/README.html#gnss
For now, I tried samples blindly with HW/device I'am supposing that should work... And get often errors!? Simple sample/HW like blinky is not always easy to get to work...
Is there a way to know which HW/device was used to create the zephyr samples in order to know minimal requirement/feature the device (that I still need to buy!) should have?
